# CustomDialog button OnClickListener not working

Tags: android

I really don't understand why I'm not able to add an OnClickListener to a button I have in a Dialog. I've tried to add it into the onCreate methods and also to add a listener after I've shown the dialog but with no luck. Here's what I have so far..

Dialog Class

```
    public class PostDialog extends DialogFragment{

    EditText textContent;
    Button sButton;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        sButton= (Button) getDialog().findViewById(R.id.sButton);
        sButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                //do something here

                getDialog().dismiss();
            }
        });
    }

    public void showDialog(Activity activity) {
        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(activity);
        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_new_post);
        //dialog.show();

        WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
        lp.copyFrom(dialog.getWindow().getAttributes());
        lp.width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
        //lp.height = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
        dialog.show();
        dialog.getWindow().setAttributes(lp);
    }

}
```

DialogXML Layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="400dp"
    android:minHeight="400dp">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:lines="11"
        android:textColor="@color/colorGreyDark"
        android:background="@drawable/new_post_background"
        android:textColorHint="@color/colorGreyDark"
        android:hint="@string/share_hint"
        android:padding="@dimen/general_margin"
        android:id="@+id/newPostEditText"
        android:layout_above="@+id/sButton" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="@string/new_post_button"
        android:textColor="@color/colorGreyDark"
        android:id="@+id/sButton"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Call to the Dialog

```
public void startNewPostActivity(View view) {
    final PostDialog postDialog = new PostDialog();
    postDialog.showDialog(this);
}
```

**EDIT: I ended up just creating the dialog straight from my main activity rather than having the dialog creation in a DialogFragment class. I was then able to successfully get the onClickListener to work**

Comment: put your click button code inside showDialog method instead of onCreate

Answer (score 0):

The view hierarchy for the dialog isn't available in onCreate.  According to the doc for [DialogFragment](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html), you are supposed to either override [onCreateView()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onCreateView%28android.view.LayoutInflater,%20android.view.ViewGroup,%20android.os.Bundle%29) to specify the view hierarchy for the Dialog, or override on [onCreateDialog()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html#onCreateDialog(android.os.Bundle)) to create the dialog yourself.

The earliest you have access to the views in the dialog is after the view hierarchy is created, then you can find view and attach listeners.  onCreate() is too early.

Answer (score 0):

```
sButton= (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.sButton);
sButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                //do something here

                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
```

put above code in your **showDialog(Activity activity)** method.

Note:Assuming that **sButton** is available in **dialog_new_post.xml** file

Comment: The Button is available (forgot to add it into my pasted XML oops..) However trying to set the listener inside of showDialog causes a NPE which is why I had guessed it was better off to go in the onCreate method but that doesn't work either

Comment: You need to add above code below **dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_new_post);** line.

Comment: I have tried this and I get a NPE

NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.app.Activity.findViewById(int)

Comment: Just remove the sButton related code from onCreate() it is giving you NPE.